# How do I get directory info for a shared dropbox folder with the Python API?

Tags: api, dropbox, shared-directory

Another dropbox user has made a folder public so anyone can get at it. They're depending on dropbox's obfuscated URLs to hide those files from most of the world, so I won't provide them here, but the pattern looks like:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/15_random_characters/25_random_characters/folder_name?dl=0

I've established that dl=0 controls whether you want to download the contents of the folder and that I can change the 0 to a 1 and get a .zip of the entire directory. This will work in a pinch, since the entire director zips to about 3 megs and I can throw out the 6-7 useless files each time, but I'd rather do this properly and get just the one file. This url works even if I'm not logged in to dropbox, and even works with wget, which simplifies my life immensely.

Supposedly, [there is a way to access shared folder data](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shared-folders), but I've tried all sorts of combinations of the data in the URL, and can't identify the "shared folder ID" that the dropbox doc says should go into their url template:

https://api.dropbox.com/1/shared_folders/

I'll be accessing these files on a daily basis in an automated fashion, so I'd rather not have to authenticate with dropbox via oauth. It shouldn't be necessary, given the unprotected status of the files.

Anyone have a way that I can get a "directory listing" on a shared folder, given the URL info I have, and then download a specific file from that list? I've gotten far enough through the (Python) Core API to authenticate and peruse my own, private, files. It's the ones that the whole world has access to that I seem to have trouble with.  =]

Comment: The shared link for the folder (the link containing "/sh/") does not contain the shared folder ID necessary for use with the API. (Even if it did, you'd have to call the API with an access token for a user authorized to access that shared folder.) Anyway, unfortunately, there isn't an API for interacting with shared links like this (e.g., to list files in it), but we're tracking this as a feature request.

Comment: As mentioned above, the URL is sufficient to access the folder and files within, without logging in. (I'm able to browse the folder in Chrome's incognito mode and I can use wget to grab a .zip of the folder.) If there's a way to get at the data through the .../shared_folder/... url, that would be optimal. Barring that, I'll fall back to the .zip hack I mentioned.